How to show the entry with an empty relation
So, my assumptions were wrong, took my time to redo the search of the problem, so I've edited completely my question :
My problem is that in my page, some entries don't show up. But exporting all my data in excel show them no problem. It's probably a twig problem, but since I'm not sure, I'll prefer ask. Here's the code :
{% for l in listXl.data %}
    <tr><td>{{ l.livre }}</td>
    <td>{% set x = 1 %} {% for a in l.auteurs %}{{ a.nom }} {{a.prenom}} {% if x != l.auteurs|length %} <br/> {% endif %} {% set x = x+1 %}{% endfor %}</td>

The repository function :
public function findAllLimit(int $page, $filtre = "", int $limit = 25, ):array
   {
       $result = [];
       $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('l')
        ->innerJoin('l.auteurs', 'a')
        ->innerJoin('l.editeur', 'e')
        ->innerJoin('l.etatLibris', 'x')
        ->andWhere('l.xl_livre LIKE :val')
        ->orWhere('a.nom LIKE :val')
        ->orWhere('a.prenom LIKE :val')
        ->orWhere('l.xl_num LIKE :val')
        ->orWhere('e.nom LIKE :val')
        ->setParameter('val', "%".$filtre."%")
           ->orderBy('l.xl_num', 'DESC')
          ->setMaxResults($limit)
          ->setFirstResult($page * $limit - $limit);

          $paginator = new Paginator($query);
          $data = $paginator->getQuery()->getResult();

          if(empty($data)) return $result;

          //Calcul nb de pages
          $pages = ceil($paginator->count() / $limit);

          $result['data'] = $data;
          $result['pages'] = $pages;
          $result['page'] = $page;
          $result['limit'] = $limit;

          return $result;
   }

The export function just select all lines, ordering the same way as the function show there.
Does twig don't know what to do when the array is empty ? Because it don't show any data for the line when there is no "auteurs". It's a problem, since I can't edit the datas in the site, I have to work directly on the database, and that's a big problem.
I hope you can help me with that. Thank you in advance.

I suspect you are looking for a leftJoin instead of an innerJoin in the case where a value might be null. Thank a look at This post or this post for more information on the differences.
